# Deleting elements in linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

This appeared on one of the old exams on algorithms and data structure. It seems pretty simple but I need some help with understanding why it works.

The goal is to delete certain atoms from a singly linked list using only a pointer to head.

The structure of atom is:

```
struct at {
 int element;
 struct at *next;
};
typedef struct at atom;
```

The solution is:

```
void delete(atom **head)
{
  while((*head)){
    if((*head)->element%2){ /*just a condition for deleting*/
      (*head)=(*head)->next; /*deleting the atom*/
    } else {
       head= &(*head)->next; 
    }
   }
 }
```

What I understand is that, in this function, "*head" is the actual head (pointer to the first atom) and "head" is a pointer to the actual head. Clearly, since I'll actually change the head and contents of the list, I need to pass a pointer to head.

I just can't understand how head= &(*head)->next seems to work. I've tried putting it down on paper and still can't make any sense of it. How does it not change anything and just jump to the next atom?

Comment: `head` Is a pointer to a pointer. Just like any other pointer, it holds the address of an entity of its underlying type, in this case a pointer to an `atom`. Like all pointers (`void*` notwithstanding), `*p = ...` dereferences the pointer and assigns to what it points to. Whereas `p = ...` changes the address held in the pointer. Related, unless the memory management is taken care of somewhere else, this "solution" abandons the nodes disconnected from the given linked list; i.e., it's a recipe for a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `*head` is the actual head (pointer to the first atom) and `head` is a pointer to the actual head.In statement `head= &(*head)->next;`
we are updating `head` (which contains address of the actual head) with the address of address of node next to actual head node.

Now `head` is a pointer which store the address of head to next node not head node i.e next atom.

**Consider a list**
1->2->3->4->5

in this case initially head contains the address node 1, and *head is node 1 itself.
Now when we say `head= &(*head)->next;` it means `head` will store address of node 2.If we will do `*head` it return node 2.